# How to use built-in css color classes of material design in Polymer.dart?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I am trying to test and port one of the official neon-animation example from JS to Dart.

This is the original [js demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=neon-animated-pages) and [js source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/tree/master/demo/grid),
and this is my implemented [Dart demo](http://easonpai.github.io/using-neon-animation/) and [Dart source](https://github.com/EasonPai/using-neon-animation/tree/master)

2 problems encountered:

1. in JS version, the color of div is assigned with class, ex: class="card green-300", green-300 shows a material color, and the same way is not working in Dart version, so **what is the approach in Dart to assign a built-in material design color with css class?**

   **html**:

   ```
   <div id="[[index]]" class="card green-300" on-tap="onTapped">
      <span>[[item.value]]</span>
   </div>
   ```
2. All layout is defined in html, so the result is supposed to be the same. **But in my Dart version the layout is broken. Maybe some additional settings is needed?**

   **result of js**:
   [image]

   **result of dart**:
   [image]

**--updated 2016.05.24--**

```
Problem 1 is solved.
```

As Günter Zöchbauer indicated, I forgot to import html that contains those handwritten & pre-defined css color classes. I guess we just have to enumerate all colors and pre-defined those css classes somewhere. Thanks Günter.

```
Problem 2 is about solved.
```

It is strange that the same content built by polymer.js works correctly on chrome v50 & v51, but polymer.dart's only works on chrome v51.

Comment: Is this only in Dartium or also in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: oops, didn't noticed my demo page is down, I fixed it. The problem exists in both Dartium and Chrome. I didn't try FireFox. demo is here: http://easonpai.github.io/using-neon-animation/

Comment: The colors seem correct to me. The layout seems broken.

Comment: oh, color shows correctly that is because i workarounded the problem, if i don't workaround it, we can see nothing and it will be very difficult to explain my problem, maybe i should leave it as what is was?

Comment: It would be interesting to see what it looks like with and without the workaround.

Comment: I just removed workarounds (see http://easonpai.github.io/using-neon-animation/). actually neon-animation and broken layout is still there, but we can't see it because colors of Material Design is not working correctly

Comment: I saw the update in your question. Does this mean the layout problem is not yet solved?

Comment: yes, layout problem is not yet solved.

Comment: But your demo at http://easonpai.github.io/using-neon-animation/ looks fine except the missing colors.

Comment: The `grid-view` also is set to `display: flex-inline` while previously it was `display: block`.

Comment: That is weird. Layout problem is still there on my chrome, dartium and safari.

Comment: I tried with Chrome. What do you see when you open the link above and open Chrome devtools and mouse-over the elements. I see them highlighted in full size. Even without devtools I see the numbers of the fields at the right place. Just saw, when I now open it it even shows the right colors.

Comment: yes, i just updated my demo with problem 1 solved. colors are back! i still see layout like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/1h9Yf.png, they are not placed at right place like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/WuYJn.png. If you see "display: flex-inline| flex" other than "display: block" that is because i am trying to revise it according to your reply, but no matter how i change it, problem is still there on my machine, weird enough!

Comment: For me it looks like the 2nd image. Can you try Ctrl+F5 to force-reload?

Comment: Really appreciate for your help. It is okey if layout problem cannot be solved, i used to layout div with iron-flex-layout, they never surprise me.

Comment: tried, force-reload and incognito window makes no difference. and my chrome version is 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit) if you want to know.

Comment: When you inspect `<grid-view>` in devtools what's the value of the CSS `display` property?

Comment: i see ".grid-view-0 {
    display: flex;
    background: #000;
}"

Comment: The same here. Previously it was `display: flex-inline` but for me it still has the same (correct) layout. Maybe it's the Chrome version or something. I have 51.0.2704.54 on Linux.

Comment: holly! I opened demo on another machine (which i never develop with it) that runs Chrome Beta with version 51.0.2704.47 (64 bit), the layout is correct. Everything is clear now!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear this could be tracked down.

Comment: Thank you for spent plenty of time to help :)

Comment: I guess it's related to what JS code is generated from Dart code.  Dart polyfills some features that don't work the same in all browsers. Obviously there was some change (maybe a bug fix or a new bug) in 51 where the Polymer.js code is using a method that works the same in 50 and 51 while the code generated from Dart using this method in a way that only works in 51. It might be worth a bug report but first it would be necessary to track down what the difference is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display: block` of `<grid-view>` to `display: flex` makes it look like your first screenshot.

Comment: Do you mean change this
`:host {
            display: block;
            background: #000;
        }`

to
`:host {
            display: flex;
            background: #000;
        }`
... it is not working for me...

Comment: I just changed it in Chrome devtools on the running page. I didn't look at the source.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference but the `<style>` tag should be inside the `<template>` tag in Polymer elements.

Comment: i tried but it makes no difference.  i thought the official wiki of polymer.dart told us to put <style> outside of <template>, like https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/styling

Comment: That seems outdated. Polymer changed strategy here about a year ago.

Comment: Looks like you are missing these styles the JS demo is importing https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/blob/master/demo/shared-styles.html

Comment: OMG, outdated!? someone should drop a line on the official wiki to inform users.

Comment: And, YES! i lost the shared-style.html. now i am feeling stupid. color problem solved, thanks a lot.

Comment: The layout problem seemed to be fixed already in the updated Demo. Is your question then fully answered?